# R using list.datasets for specific groups in h5 files

Tags: r, rhdf5

I have 4 groups within my h5 file such that the following code:

```
list.datasets(spot_sims)
= [1] "/Apple/2018" "/Apple/2019" "/IBM/2018" "/IBM/2019"
```

How can I query only the IBM group without having to use index numbers?

E.g. I have tried variations of the following:

```
list.datasets(spot_sims)["\\IBM"]
```

Comment: Try with `grep` i.e. `grep("IBM", list.datasets(spot_sims), value = TRUE)`

Comment: How can I alter the above query to obtain the data within the list, e.g. something similar to `for (i in 1:simulated_years) { assign(paste0("spot_y", i), spot_sims[list.datasets(spot_sims)[i]][]) }`